# Get real id of facebook friends

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently when user try to join my app with Facebook I get his info with his real id. I want to get his friends. Currently i can get them only with taggable_friends. But there the id is not real... I need the real id, because I want the user to send message to other Facebook users in my app and when the other join my app, I will use his id to find in my database this message.

If you have any idea to make this connection, please help me.

Comment: Providing the relevant peaces of your current code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get user id's off all friends. This feature is removed in v2. Since April, 2015, you cannot use v1. Check out 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends

First you need to get `user_friends` permission for each users. Then you can use `/me/friends` to get all friends that install your app previously. Therefore you don't need id of all friends, ids of friends who install your app are sufficient. In other words, you do the matching using new user's friend ids, not the former one.

Suppose user A installs your app. You get the friends list and find there is no friends using your app. Then a new user B installs your app. If A and B are friends, then getting friends list of B will yield A as a result. Since you have id of A, and ids of B's friends (who installs your app), you can match them.

Comment: I need all friends, not only that installed the app. With taggable_friends I can get them but how to connect the id from taggable_friends and the new user that connect with the app for first time?

Comment: As far as I know there is now way to do it. Will your users sent message to their friends before their friends install your app?

Comment: Yes. I want this: I install the app and log with my fb account. Then I find interesting text there for ex. and want to share it. I see all my fb friends. I select Ersin Basaran and 'share' it with him. Then this 'share' is saved in our db and Ersin receive message in fb that he has something in our app. He install the app, login with his fb profile. The app get his id, search in the database and if there is match, it returns this 'shared' text. 
I need make this connection between personal id and 'taggable_friends' id or something like that.